# how does PHP funciton: crypt(string str, string [salt]) works? Is it possible that the salt equals to the encrypted result?

Tags: php, cryptography, md5, salt, password-hash

Recently, i learn a new web application. In its user authorization part, i find it use crypt() in PHP to authorize users. But the code is like followings:

```
if ($auth != crypt(md5($cdata), $auth))
{
   exit(); //exit
}
//the code after authorization;
```

Is it possible that the salt in this function could equal to the encrypted result so that the code after authorization can be executed?
I cannot understand this at all. So keen for answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, avoid using `crypt()` and `md5()`, do use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. See http://php.net/password_hash for more details. These functions are very easy to use, require no configuration, and are available for almost any PHP version down to 5.3.9 (with a PHP lib if the native function isn't yet included).

Second, yes, the created hash (even with crypt) does contain the salt, and that's why `password_verify()` requires to know about the previously created hash value of the password. It will read the salt part and the hash parameters from it, hash the new given password with the salt and parameters, and if the result from the currently given password is the same as the old hash, the password is correct.

To illustrate:

```
echo password_hash('foo', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

> $2y$10$ODIL7VQp1aLOfLrEv2rPQ.wFIbBr7hvQtMTuw4B4xnB/qI7nnMpVO
```

`$2y$` signals the hash algorithm (Which is BCrypt), the following `10$` is the parameter for BCrypt (10 rounds of hashing), and the remainder of the string is partly the salt and partly the hash value. Note that calling `password_hash()` will randomly generate a salt value and thus return different strings every time.

```
var_dump(password_verify('foo', '$2y$10$ODIL7VQp1aLOfLrEv2rPQ.wFIbBr7hvQtMTuw4B4xnB/qI7nnMpVO'));

> bool(true)
```

Verifying the password is always as simple as this: Pass new password and old hash to `password_verify()` - if they match, it will return `true`.

Comment: thx a lot ! i carefully read ur answer, but still don't get it. U said the old hash and new password part, i totally agree. But still not mention if there exists the encrypted result equals to the salt value. Or more specifically, how can i create $auth so that the Equation: $auth == crypt(md5($cdata), $auth) may satisfy? Thanks again.

Comment: As I said: Don't use `crypt()`, don't use `md5()`, don't use `==` to compare - all these things are very bad for security. DO use `password_hash()` to create the hash value, and `password_verify()` to check if a given password matches the hash.